# Can't show a display none inside a table

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-table

I'm having a problem with style.display.

I want to show a submit box (which is inside a table) when I change a number and it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
<head>
<script>
function changedisp(Section){  
    if (Section.style.display=="none"){  
        Section.style.display=""  
    }  
    else{  
    Section.style.display="none"  
    }  
}  
function raisenumber(s,s1) {
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById(s).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(s).innerHTML = x*1 + 1;
    changedisp(s1);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><b>ID</b></th>
        <th><b>number</b></th>
        <th><b>buttoon</b></th>
        <th><b>submit</b></th>
    </tr>
    <form action="modifica_inventario.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td> <b id="cell1A">item number1</b></td>
        <td> <b id="cell2A">10</b></td>
        <td> <button id="cell3A" type="button" onClick=raisenumber("cell2A","cell4A")>+1</button></td>
        <td> <b id="cell4A" style="display: none;"> <input type="submit" value="submit"/></b> &nbsp </td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <b id="cell1B">item number1</b></td>
        <td> <b id="cell2B">10</b></td>
        <td> <button id="cell3B" type="button" onClick=raisenumber("cell2B","cell4B")>+1</button></td>
        <td> <b id="cell4B" style="display: none;"> <input type="submit" value="submit"/></b> &nbsp </td>  
    </tr>
    </form>
</table>
</body>
```

Well I don't know why it's not showing on and off the submit button every time a press the button...

I also tried replacing

```
changedisp(s1);
```

by

```
s1.style.display="";
```

Any comments about this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the actual element you are trying to hide and show to your changedisp function. In your code you are just passing the ID name of the element. Try this...

```
function raisenumber(s,s1) {
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById(s).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(s).innerHTML = x*1 + 1;
    changedisp(document.getElementById(s1));
}
```

notice `changedisp(document.getElementById(s1));` passes the actual element instead of just the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it to a display type explicitly:

```
Section.style.display="inline";
```

Or inline-block, or block, or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

A `<B>` is by default display:inline, so trying setting to "inline" not the empty string, "".